# Network options when app is in not running or terminated state

Tags: ios, objective-c, network-programming

We are building an iOS iPhone app that needs to check-in with a server on a 12 hour basis. This is needed to let the server know that the app is still using it's service on the server. To our understanding this is possible when the app is in background state (not showing on the foreground) via backgound fetch or remote notifications.

But this is not possbile when the app is not running or terminated, when the app is in these states then there is no way to initiate communication with a server. Is this statement corret? Is it possible initiate the communication after a device bootup, is it then possible to send a small keep alive message to te sever?

The background fetch and responding to remote notifcations is not possible in the not running and termenating states(?), so we cannot use these mecahnisms for this purpose. If that is the case are there any other solutions that we can try? Or is it just not possible?

We looked at many sources on the internet but some say that it is possible and others say it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Silent Push Notifications. Here is the thing, if the app is in background mode or suspended state, you will be fine. If the app was killed by the user, you have a problem.

You can always send a silent push notification, and wait for a service call made from the device to your service. If there is a response, it means the app was in background or suspended, and then you can go ahead and do whatever you need to do. If no request is made, it means that app was killed. Then you might want a sent a non silent push letting the user of that device know that he needs to launch the app or something like that. I don't know how you are going to work around it, but that could be a possibility.

I would tell you to take a look at NSURLSession and Background NSURLSessionConfiguration as well, but you will run into the same issue. If the user manually terminates the app, you need to find a work around to set up that connection to the server, and that will imply the user to somehow launch your application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in short there is no way to lauch the application in the background and let it sent and receive Some small data on it's own When the app(right after device bootup) is not running of is terminated?

Comment: There is no way if the app was terminated, otherwise a silent push notification would solve your issue...